# How do I make a video background with python Flask

Tags: html, css, flask

I am trying to make the mainpage.html to load the video.mp4 in the css folder. I have tried to copy the video file in all the folders. But I simply can not make it play the video I have a blank white page.

```
   root
    --static
      --video.mp4  
      --css
        --mainpage.css
    --templates   
      --MainPage.html
    --env
    --__pycache__
```

My HTML code looks as follows in `mainpage.html`

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/frontpage.css') }}"
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='video1.mp4') }}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/frontpage.css">

      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>  
    <head>

      <div id="videoBC">
      <video id="videoBG" poster="poster.JPG" autoplay muted loop>
      <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML seems a bit ... interesting.
How about:

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/frontpage.css') }}" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>  
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="videoBC">
        <video id="videoBG" poster="{{ url_for('static', filename='poster.JPG') }}" autoplay muted loop>
          <source src="{{ url_for('static', filename='video1.mp4') }}" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```